# Error CS0411 in.NET while using @Html.DisplayNameFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I am beginner in .NET and I am learning MVC pattern. I am building a demo application which demonstrate CRUD Operations on any product. Before I use any database connectivity, I decided to test it with in memory variable. My code is as below:

**Model Class**

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public String ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Price")]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Discription")]
    public String ProductDiscription { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Product/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Product{Id = 01, Price=100, ProductName="MyProduct", ProductDiscription="30 TeaBags in a pack"});
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    @model CrudAppDemo.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

<h2>Products</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">

        <table class="table">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</td>                        
                    </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

When I am running this code, I am getting CS0411 Error:

[image]

Comment: what a silly mistake.....i was using display name instead of property name in view. thanks guys...finally got it worked...

Comment: but i didn't get it, why visual studio was not showing any hint when i type '.' (dot) after model...it should show property name as usual

Comment: Visual studio shows all property when you press.(dot)

Comment: @halfer , Thanks buddy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter doesn't match the ones in model.
you have ProductName in model and you are trying to access Name which is not in model, same goes for description.

Write this instead.

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model. ProductDiscription)</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model. ProductDiscription)</td>                        
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the display name `[Display(Name="Name")]` as your property rather than the property itself `public String ProductName { get; set; }`.  Try changing to use the property name.

```
  <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)</td>
  <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</td>
  <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductDiscription)</td>
```